# Why is this Sybase fetch statement not working?

Tags: sybase

```
declare @coltype char(60)
declare @cname char(60)
declare col_crsr cursor for SELECT cname,coltype from sys.syscolumns
                             where tname = 'abmc_customer_user'
                               for update of cname
set cursor rows 4 for col_crsr
open col_crsr
fetch col_crsr
close col_crsr
deallocate cursor col_crsr
```

In this, after executing fetch, it should display rows but it displays execution time:0.0031sec.
What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In most dialects of SQL, you'd have a loop around the FETCH to get multiple rows, and you'd also specify where the data is to go (which variables it is to be fetched into), and you'd have to take some steps to get the data displayed.

Comment: declare @coltype char(60)
declare @cname char(60)
declare @i int
select @i=3
declare col_crsr cursor for SELECT cname,coltype from sys.syscolumns  where tname = 'abmc_customer_user' for update of cname
set cursor rows 20 for col_crsr
open col_crsr
while @i<5
begin
fetch col_crsr into @cname,@coltype
select @cname,@coltype
select @i=@i+1
end
close col_crsr
deallocate cursor col_crsr
hi Jonathan Leffler if i use loop like above it show only first row of cursor it wont disply furter rows.
plz help me and tel me what  i hav to change to display all rows of cursor

Comment: declare @coltype char(60)
declare @cname char(60)
declare @i int
select @i=3
declare col_crsr cursor for SELECT cname,coltype from sys.syscolumns  where tname = 'abmc_customer_user' for update of cname
set cursor rows 20 for col_crsr
open col_crsr
while @i<5
begin
fetch col_crsr into @cname,@coltype
select @cname,@coltype
select @i=@i+1
end
close col_crsr
deallocate cursor col_crsr
hi Jonathan Leffler if i use loop like above it show only first row of cursor it wont disply furter rows.
plz help me and tel me what  i hav to change to display all rows of cursor

Answer (score 0):

You could try it like this to loop through the cursor and fetch the values into your variables and then SELECT the variables...

declare @coltype char(60)

declare @cname char(60)

declare col_crsr cursor for SELECT cname,coltype from sys.syscolumns
                             where tname = 'abmc_customer_user'
                               for update of cname

set cursor rows 4 for col_crsr

open col_crsr WITH HOLD

fetch col_crsr INTO @coltype,@cname

WHILE (@@sqlstatus = 0)

BEGIN

SELECT @coltype,@cname

FETCH NEXT col_crsr INTO @coltype,@cname

END

close col_crsr

deallocate cursor col_crsr